# Adding attributes in 2 arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I have 2 arraylist which the records are stored as objects.
First arraylist object has attributes such as patient id , totaltestcost, totaltreatmentcost. 
Second arraylist object has attributes such as patient id, totalservicecharges.

Now my problem is when i try to add up the total, meaning totaltestcost + totaltreatmentcost + totalservicecharges, for a given patient id, i cant add up the total and display it.

I found out that that since it is in 2 arrays i need to search the arrays by the id and get the costs.

This is the way how i  search a patient record 
 public patient_class searchrecord(ArrayList patients, String search)
 {

```
    for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop


        if(patient.getid().equals(search))
        {

            return patient;
        }
    return null;
```

}

Is there a possibility which i can modify this code to get the costs stored in 2 arrays ?

for example like this :-

public int searchrecord(ArrayList patients, String search)
 {

```
    for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop


        if(patient.getid().equals(search))
        {

           int total= patient.gettotaltestcost + patient.gettotaltreatmentcost
        }
    return null;
```

}
But if i use the above method ill only be able to get the total of totaltestcost+totaltreatmentcost , i need to obtain the servicechargecost as well but its in another array.

So how can i do this ?

Thank you for your time.

Edit :-

Finally i managed to do it guys and here is how i did it :-

public String addtotal(ArrayList patients, String search,ArrayListpatient2,String search2)
 {
  int total;

```
    for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop

    {
        if(patient.getid().equals(search))
        {



        for(patient_class patient3: patient2)
        {
            if(patient3.getid().equals(search2))
            {
                total=patient.gettreatmentcost()+patient.gettestcost()+patient3.getservicecharge();

                return Double.toString(total);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    return null;
```

}

i passed in both arrays at once.

Thanks everyone for sharing your answers , next time ill definitely use treemaps

Comment: In my opinion you are using the wrong datastructure for the job.

A map structure where the patient id is the key and the value is the patient object would be suited much better for the job. It would allow a cost of O(1) on lookup.

Comment: the thing its too late to change the structure now ,i need to give this project on coming monday. Please help if possible. 

Thanks

Comment: Well, I'd like to help, but i would need some more info on the second array. I only see 1 array describing a list of patients. But I have no idea what the second one looks like. Is this second list also a patient list, and if so, what method are we looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole lot of things wrong with your code, but coding to your functionality and disregarding the proper [java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) (which you clearly ignore for some reason and which I'm not going to fix). I came up with this. 1 method to find your patient in your list, and 1 method to calculate the patient total from the 2 lists.

```
public patient_class findPatient(List<patient_class> patients, String search) {
    for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop
        if(patient.getid().equals(search))
        {
           return patient;
        }
    }
    return null; // no patient found matching the search id
 }

 public int calculatePatientTotal(List<patient_class> patientsList1, List<patient_class> patientsList2, String search){
    patient_class patientInList1 = findPatient(patientsList1,search);// assuming unique id
    patient_class patientInList2 = findPatient(patientsList2,search);// assuming unique id

    int total=0;
    // calc general total
    if(patientInList1!=null{
        // I'm assuming you put these getters in methods instead of public properties!
        // hence the brackets at the end
        total= patientInList1.gettotaltestcost() + patientInList1.gettotaltreatmentcost();
    } 

    // add any extra charges
    if(patientInList2!=null ){
        // I'm assuming this is the method that calculates the other charges in that patient object.
        total+= patientInList2.getOtherCharges();
    }

    return total;
 }
```

Next time I would recommend you think about the proper structures to use and mainly to not scatter same info over different items.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget about `else` keyword. All your two method's will be return only `null`

You need to write somethink like this:

```
public patient_class searchrecord(ArrayList patients, String search) {

for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop


    if(patient.getid().equals(search))
    {
        return patient;
    }
    else 
        return null;
}
```

and this

```
public int searchrecord(ArrayList patients, String search) {

for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop


    if(patient.getid().equals(search))
    {
       int total= patient.gettotaltestcost + patient.gettotaltreatmentcost;
       return total;
    }
    else
       return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to change the data structure for a map. If you have to use two arrayLists you can write a method that would return you the desired result as an integer.
It is inefficient tho.

```
public static int total(List<Patient> firstList, List<Patient> secondList, int search)
{
    int total = 0;

    for(Patient p:firstList)
    {
        if(p.getId() == search)
        {
            total = p.getServiceCost();
            for(Patient p2 : secondList)
            {
                if(p2.getId()== search)
                {
                    total += p2.gettotaltestcost() + p2.gettotaltreatmentcost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

That's from top of my head without testing, so you there might be errors. I assumed that id is an integer, you can change it to .equals if it's a String. I hope it helps.
If your type is patient_class then of course change all Patient to patient_class. In your main you can do something like

```
List<patient_class> list1 = new ArrayList<patient_class>();
List<patient_class> list2 = new ArrayList<patient_class>();
// populate those lists 
int search = 12;    
int result = total(list1, list2, int search);
```

Btw you can pass any number of lists into a method as arguments as long as you specify thei

```
public int(ArrayList a, ArrayList b)
```

wouldn't compile.